# Dto custom validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, class-validator

How do I validate my timestamp at DTO level? I need `trackingEndTimestamp` to be greater than `trackingStartTimestamp`:

```
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsNotEmpty, IsNumber, IsString, Validate } from "class-validator";
import { CustomTextLength } from "./CustomTextLength";

export class UserActivityDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userId: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  loginId: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  trackingStartTimestamp: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  @Validate(CustomTextLength, [trackingStartTimestamp, 20], {
    message: "End date cannot be greater then end date",
  })
  trackingEndTimestamp: number;
}
```

Here at @validate I want to pass `trackingStartTimestamp`  value as a parameter

plz Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass it, you can find it in the validate handler.

```
validate(value: any, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments) {
  console.log(validationArguments.object.trackingStartTimestamp );
}
```